# <small> tag is being auto inserted

Tags: theme-development

The tag is being automatically inserted in my HTML document. It is only being applied in my home page. I've already disabled all plugins but it is still there.

My website is https://www.casinowired.com

This is the part where `<small>` tags are being weirdly inserted.
[image]

These tags should not be in here.
[image]

Anyone has an idea what's going on?

---

### UPDATE

I restored from a backup so the issue with the columns was solved. But now it inserts small tags in the bottom part of my home page.

[image]

These small tags should not be here
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been solved.

In my grid, I'm only showing 30 characters of excerpt in my cards. I use this line of code:

```
$post_excerpt = ( get_the_excerpt() ) ? mb_substr( get_the_excerpt(), 0, 30 ) . '...' : '';
```

In one of my post's excerpt, there's an html code written and with the code above the html code is being cut. I still don't know why there are small html tags being added when an html code is being cut.

To solve the issue I added the code below:

```
$post_excerpt = wp_strip_all_tags( $post_excerpt );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of wordpress editor which put some raw elements when it find space between code..  if you are adding external html code do one thing before adding it, make it minify then add it

use this took or anyone else for minification https://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

it will resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm using wpbakery page builder and post listing is a custom shortcode that I developed. I inserted the shortcode to an html element. I checked the text version in the wordpress editor and it is minified already.